# Share amplify build log file via SNS notification

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Can anyone please answer my query - Is there any way to get the build log file of AWS Amplify ?
I'm getting build status (success | fail) email notification via SNS, and I want to add-on the build log attachment with the SNS notification configs .

I am getting an email with body via SNS and looking to add build logs file as an attachment with the same